# If conditional to test if an entry does not have a relationship

Tags: relationships

I have a relationship field, and I want to display entries only if they are NOT populated with the relationship.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="message" orderby="date" sort="asc" {gv_param_disable_default}}
        <ul>

            <li>
            {series_association}
            here's what doesn't seem to be working --> {if series_association:title == no_results}
            <h3><u>{title}</u> - <i><h5 class="inline-header">{message_date format='%F %j, %Y'}</h5></i></h3> 
            <p>{if message_speaker}<i>Speaker:</i> {message_speaker}{/if}
            <p>{if message_scripture}<i>Scripture Reference:</i> {message_scripture}{/if}
            <p>{message_summary}</p>
            <audio src="{message_audio}" preload="none" />
            {/if}
            {/series_association}
            </li>

        </ul>


    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

How would I code this to make it show only entries without a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use no_results but like:

```
{if series_association:no_results}
    --- your content ---
{/if}
```